# R Datatable: Colorize two columns based on a third's value

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I just don't get this to run. Colorize200dMA is either -1, 0, or 1. In the case of -1 '200d MA' should be a red cell, in case of 0 it shouldn't be colorized and in the case of 1 it should be green. But mostly nothing is colorized at all in the end or only the red (first value), but never the green one.

```
    datatable(ResultDF,selection = 'single', options=list(dom='ft', pageLength=50)) %>%
    #datatable(ResultDF, options=list(dom='ft')) %>%
      formatStyle(
        '200d MA', 'Colorize200dMA'
        background = styleEqual(c(-1, 1), c('#e6b8b7', '#d8e4bc'))
      ) %>%
#       formatStyle(
#         '50v200d MA', "Colorize50v200dMA",
#         backgroundColor = styleInterval(0, c('#e6b8b7', '#d8e4bc'))
#       ) %>%
      formatDate(c(3,6,8), "toLocaleDateString")
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to give 3 colors, even if one of them is 'white': http://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You could directly implement some easy js/jquery code which would give you a lot more options to colorize your entire table.

For example,

```
datatable(ResultDF,selection = 'single', options=list(
dom='ft',
pageLength=50,
rowCallback = JS('function(row, data) {
        if (parseFloat(data[x]) == -1 )
          $("td:eq(x)", row).css("background-color", "red");
        else if (parseFloat(data[x]) == 0 )
          $("td:eq(x)", row).css("background-color", "white");
        else if (parseFloat(data[x]) == 1 )
          $("td:eq(x)", row).css("background-color", "green");
      }'
      )
))
```

where x is your column, starting with 0 in js ( eg. r column 2 is 1 for js ).

You can add conditional formats this way, column 2 setting color for column 3 for example.

Comment: datatable(ResultDF,selection = 'single', 
              options=list(
                dom='ft', 
                pageLength=50,
                rowCallback = I('function(row, data) {
                  if (parseFloat(data[3]) == -1 )
                    $("td:eq(1)", row).css("background-color", "red");
                  else if (parseFloat(data[3]) == 1 )
                    $("td:eq(1)", row).css("background-color", "green");
                }'
                )
                )) %>%
      formatDate(c(3,5,6), "toLocaleDateString")
    })

Comment: Sorry, i think I('function is deprecated, try ...JS('function... instead. Does it work for you ?